# Why would a Unity3D app [exported to to an Xcode project] fail because ip_unity_plugin.bundle has "unsealed contents present in the bundle root"?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, unity-game-engine, app-store

I am a Swift developer submitting an app made by a Unity3D developer colleague which is destined for the App Store. The Xcode project has this file in it:

```
Frameworks/Plugins/x86_64/ip_unity_plugin.bundle
```

...which I presume is required in order to run Unity within an iPhone app (yes, no?)

When validating the latest archive of the build I get this warning:

```
Code signing "ip_unity_plugin.bundle" failed.
View distribution logs for more information.
```

[image]

The logs state that:

```
.../myClients.app/ip_unity_plugin.bundle: unsealed contents present in the bundle root
```

Which has me like ‍♀️

Any ideas anyone?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bundle is actually the instant preview library for Google Daydream.

If you're building for release it's safe to delete it from the Assets/Plugins directory of Unity.

Alternatively you can mark the bundle to not be compiled by changing it's metadata in the inspector. You might also find that this problem goes away if you update to a newer version of instance preview.